# Nested loop output error:subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I am trying to find out percentage of confidence in Local government from a survey data set. The data set is time series data from 2001 to 2018 and captures the response of Target variable as "A fair amount","A great deal", "Not at all" and "Not very Much". 
The time series analysis of Year has been done using loop to identify percentage confidence,but I am facing problem with the segregating it state wise using nested loop and error  "subscript out of bounds" is coming.

I have used the same code for running only year from 2001 to 2018 and it runs fine. Can anyone also help me how to use aggregate function to resolve this?

```
data<-read.csv("maindata.csv")
state<-unique(data$Respondent.state.of.residence)
Year<-seq(2001,2018,1)
output<-matrix(ncol=18,nrow = 51)


for(i in state[1]:state[51]){
  A<-subset(data,data$Respondent.state.of.residence==state[i])
for(j in Year[1]:Year[18]){
 B<-subset(A,A$Year.of.Interview==j) 
 C<-subset(B,B$Trust.and.Confidence.in.Local.Government=="A fair amount")
 D<-subset(B,B$Trust.and.Confidence.in.Local.Government=="A great deal")
 output[j,]<-(nrow(D)*mean(D$Weight)+nrow(C)*mean(C$Weight))/nrow(B)*100

}
}
```

The output should have a matrix of 18 columns specifying year and 51 rows of state.

Comment: When you do `for(j in Year[1]:Year[18])`, `j` is going to get the actual values from `Year` (which I assume are numbers). You then use `j` to subset `output`, but since you're grabbing the actual years, it's trying to put the result into, for example, the 2018th row of `output`. You probably want `for(j in 1:18)` or `for(j in seq_along(Year))` to get values that can be used as indices.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your data using `dput()`. You're more likely to get help if others can reproduce your problem. See [mcve]